# Tell FragmentTabHost not to load any tabs until touched

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

Hey all, quick question..

Right now i have a fragmenttabhost with 4 tabs and by default tab 0 is loaded when the application is started up,  this makes sense.  However, i do not want to load any tabs until the specific tab is touched.  Simply because tab0 does a decent amount of work that does not need to be done unless touched.

Ive though about passing a true/false to the bundle to show it or not:

mTabHost.addTab(createTab("tab1", "test1", R.drawable.ico1), TabClass1.class, false);
mTabHost.addTab(createTab("tab2", "test2", R.drawable.ico2), TabClass2.class, false);
mTabHost.addTab(createTab("tab3", "test3", R.drawable.ico3), TabClass3.class, false);
mTabHost.addTab(createTab("tab4", "test4", R.drawable.ico4), TabClass4.class, false);

So in the oncreateview would look something like this:

```
public View  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getArguments();  
    //pseudo
    if(true )return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_messages, container, false);
    else return null;
}
```

but it seems like there should be an easier way to say "ok heres my tabs dont load them until touched"

I tried setting the curretTab to -1 but that didnt do anything.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have u resolved your problem ? I am facing the same issue here . Please let me know if you solved your problems.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do your job in

```
setUserVisibleHint()
```

There can be some issues if it is called before onCreateView or you might want not to get those events until onResume is called.
Extend your tabs with this Fragment. It will call onVisible not earlier than onResume and will provide subsequent updates if setUserVisibleHint is called by the system.

[UserVisibleHintFragment](https://github.com/Doctoror/PureFM/blob/master/purefm/src/main/java/com/docd/purefm/ui/fragments/UserVisibleHintFragment.java)

And do your stuff in

```
onVisible()
```

Though I'm not sure that TabHost will call setUserVisibleHint (at least ViewPager does)